# Synchronous (non-passive) scroll events

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Browsers made `scroll` events asynchronous (i.e. `{passive: true}`) a while back. For my use case, synchronous provides a better user experience.

What are the ways to regain synchronous scroll events, so that I can make DOM manipulations whenever the `(scrollLeft, scrollTop, clientWidth, clientHeight)` rectangle changes but before the scroll has been rendered?

As a weird workaround, opening and closing Dev Tools in Firefox makes events synchronous, which is how I noticed that synchronous provides a better user experience. Also setting `apz.disable_for_scroll_linked_effects` to true makes events synchronous. Also in Safari (desktop) they always seem to be synchronous.

Things I've tried:

- `div.addEventListener('scroll', update, {passive: false})` but `passive: false` is ignored.
- `Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(div), 'scrollTop', {get: ..., set: ...})` but the setter isn't called.
- `div.addEventListener('wheel', update, {passive: false})` but I'm not sure it's possible to map from `deltaY` -> updated `scrollTop`, plus it doesn't address scrolling via the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible, you will have to get into the realm of fakery.  There is an interesting writeup about how it was (or used to be?) done in code mirror [here](https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/a-pathological-scrolling-model.html)

The basic idea is to cause a scrollbar to be rendered on some element of the correct height and respond to scroll events on that to update the thing the user actually sees.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link! I think you're right. Interestingly I stumbled upon a hack to get synchronous scroll events to fix codemirror's behaviour in Firefox's devtools itself: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/76a83d0a218837ba6937d6a0fac51cb0008c2334/devtools/client/shared/sourceeditor/editor.js#L382-L403

Comment: @Max Nice find!  Monday.com also has an article that basically does the same thing: https://engineering.monday.com/our-journey-to-understand-scrolling-across-different-browsers/.  It's a shame scroll events don't have an API to turn this off.  Async scroll is nice 99% of time, but looks very janky when you need to update other parts of the UI in lockstep especially on heavier pages.  I have a timeline that is clearly lagging behind by a few pixels when scrolling, and when I have many elements it starts skipping around and sometimes pausing to catch up.

Comment: Late catching up - but isn't the issue here that there are many ways a user can scroll, mousewheel is only one, they can use keys or they can grab the scrollbar and drag it e.g. ?